# Create a statically linked shared library

Tags: compilation, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, icc

Is it possible to create a shared library which is itself statically linked, i.e. it does not depend on other shared libraries?

Let me be a little bit more concrete..
I want to create a shared library, say mylib.so, which makes use of some other special libraries (in my case its intel mkl and openMP). Since I have installed these libraries I can build mylib.so and include it in other programs without any problem.
However, if I want to use the library (or the executables including it) on another machine I first have to install all the intel stuff. Is there a way to avoid this? My first try was to add the option `-static` when building mylib.so but this doesn't seem to do anything..

I'm using icc..

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a shared library which is itself statically linked, i.e. it does not depend on other shared libraries?

Not on Linux, not when using GLIBC (your shared library will *always* depend on at least `ld-linux*.so*`).

> I want to create a shared library, say mylib.so, which makes use of some other special libraries (in my case its intel mkl and openMP).

There is no problem<sup>1</sup> statically linking Intel MKL and OpenMP libraries into `mylib.so` -- you just don't want to depend on *these* libraries dynamically (in other words, you are asking for an impossible thing which you don't actually *need*).

To do so, you need two things:

1. Link `mylib.so` with *archive* versions of the libraries you don't want to depend on dynamically, e.g. `gcc -o mylib.so -shared mylib.c .../libmkl.a ...`
2. The libraries which you want to statically link into `mylib.so` must have been built with position-independent code (i.e. with `-fPIC` flag).

**Update:**

> What if the archived version isn't available?

Then you can't link it into your library.

> Eg I'm using intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/libstdc++.so and there is no corresponding .a file..

This is a *special case*: you wouldn't want to link that version into your library *even if it were available*.

Instead, your program should use the version *installed* on the target system.

Having two separate versions of `libstdc++` (e.g. one statically linked, and the other dynamically linked) into a single process will end very badly -- either with a crash, or with silent stack or heap corruption.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that linking in somebody else's library and distributing it may have licensing implications.

Comment: What if the archived version isn't available? Eg I'm using intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/libstdc++.so and there is no corresponding .a file..